# Showing $|f(z)| \leq |z|$ inside the unit ball, given some conditions?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be a holomorphic function inside the unit disc, so that $f(0) = 0$ and $|f(z)| \leq 1$ for $|z| = 1$. Show that $|f(z)| \leq |z|$ inside the unit ball.

Does this follow immediately from the Cauchy inequalities?

They state that if $f$ is holomorphic in an open set that contains the closure of a disc $D$ centered at $z_0$ and of radius $R$, then

$$|f^{(n)}(z_0)| \leq \frac{n!||f||_C}{R^n}$$

Can I just take a disc D that is centered anywhere within the unit disc, and take its radius to be some $\epsilon$?

Setting $n = 0$, we then have that $|f(z_0)| \leq ||f||_C$; when $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$, the supremium of $|f|$ on the boundary circle centered at $z_0$ becomes precisely $f(z_0)$.

Is this reasoning valid? Thanks.

Comment: This inequality is known as Schwarz lemma.

Answer (score 1):

You know that $|f|_{\partial B}\leqslant 1$ so this carries over to all of $B=B(0,1)$. That is, you have an holomorphic function $f:B(0,1)\to B(0,1)$. Consider now the function $g(z)=z^{-1}f(z)$, $g(0)=f'(0)$. Use the generalized mean value inequality over disks $0<r<1$ to conclude that $|g(z)|\leqslant r^{-1}$ for any $0<r<1$. Conclude that $|g(z)|\leqslant 1$.

Comment: Thanks -- however, may I ask what the logical flaw is in the proof I stated in the OP?

Comment: @RyanYu It is unclear to me what you're showing.

Comment: Okay -- question in regards to your proof: is it possible to use the Cauchy inequalities to show that $|g(z)| \leq 1$ instead of the generalized mean value inequality? i.e. could I set $n = 1$, and say that $||f||_C$ = 1, and have that $|g(z)| \leq 1$?

Comment: Alternatively, could I use the maximum modulus principle?